# How to extract certain parts of string?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a string of the form

```
 11 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01.06980.304 2724.04150.64-.009550          1 0 0          0 1 0  8  0  8        7  5  3      355243301884671724    17.0   15.0
```

and would like to write this to a csv-File in the form

```
1,1,1663.31578,6.045e-26,0.6292,0.0698,0.304,2724.0415,0.64,-0.00955
```

The only way I know how to do this in python is to to do something of the form

```
import csv

s = "11 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01.06980.304 2724.04150.64-.009550          1 0 0          0 1 0  8  0  8        7  5  3      355243301884671724    17.0   15.0"
with open(<path to output_csv>, "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow([s[0:2], s[2], ..., s[59:68]])
```

This works of course but seems like a very unsophisticated way to do this. Are there any better options?

Comment: Before the last element do you have a space or not?

Comment: Not a space, but a new line.

Comment: Your question doesn't say what are the rules used to split the string into columns. Also `s[0:2] == '11'` and you are saying the resulting `CSV` has `1,1` as it first two columns, which is not right.

Comment: You should be able to use `s.split()` to split the string. It don't solve the split of 11 to 1,1 at the start of the string.

Comment: @accdias all the number above are `int`s or `float`s in scientific notation and the leading zero of the floats is omitted, i.e. `0.05` -> `.05`

Comment: @Stefan but how do you handle `2724.04150.64-.009550 ` -> `2724.0415,0.64,-0.00955 `?

Comment: None of the answers posted so far are right because the OP didn't clearly state what are ALL the rules used to split the record into fields using that line as input.

Answer (score 2):

If your string has space between each element, easiest way would be:

```
s = "11 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01.06980.304 2724.04150.64-.009550          1 0 0          0 1 0  8  0  8        7  5  3      355243301884671724    17.0   15.0"
s = [x for x in s.split(" ") if x != ""] 
csv_string = ",".join(s)
```

This works even if there is multiple spaces between elements, like in the example.

--- EDIT ---

According to conversation elements has fixed breakpoints. So that info could be used like this.

```
s = "11 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01.06980.304 2724.04150.64-.009550          1 0 0          0 1 0  8  0  8        7  5  3      355243301884671724    17.0   15.0"

breakpoints = [1,2,14,24,34,40,44,55,58,65]
breakpoints.insert(0,0) # we need starting zero to make for loop work
elements = []
for i in range(len(breakpoints)-1):
    elements.append(s[breakpoints[i]:breakpoints[i+1]].strip())
",".join(elements)
```

This method also get rid of extra whitespaces because it is stripping substring before it is inserted to the elements list.

Comment: But there are elements that are not separated by spaces.. This is the whole point of the question

Comment: Oh yes, I just noticed very first elements  "11 1663.315780" -> "1,1,1663.315780". How I could know when 11 is one element and when two? There is no way for computer to know that. If the string we have has fixed places where it should be split, could you write an array of those "breakpoints"?

Comment: The breakpoints stay consistent over all the entries. They would be something like `[1,2,14,24,34,40,44,55,58,65]`

Comment: @peak_finding_prob: I updated the answer for scenario with fixed breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

If this:

```
 11 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01.06980.304 2724.04150.64-.009550
```

Is really supposed to be this:

```py
s =  "11 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01.06980.304 2724.04150.64 -.009550"
```

Then it is very easy:

```py
print(s.split(" "))
```

Otherwise you will need to do the last bit of splitting manually:

```py
s = " 11 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01.06980.304 2724.04150.64-.009550  "
parts = s.split(" ")
last = parts.pop().split("-")
parts += last
print(parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `s.split()` for splitting the string by whitespaces.

```
>>> s = " 11 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01.06980.304 2724.04150.64-.009550          1 0 0          0 1 0  8  0  8        7  5  3      355243301884671724    17.0   15.0"
>>> s.split()
['11', '1663.315780', '6.045E-26', '6.292E-01.06980.304', '2724.04150.64-.009550', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '8', '0', '8', '7', '5', '3', '355243301884671724', '17.0', '15.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution using pandas. You really need the element to be space separated.

```py
import pandas as pd
txt = "1 1 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01 .06980 .304 2724 .04150 .64 -.009550"

# split and put the list to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": txt.split(" ")})

# convert to numeric 
df["a"] = pd.to_numeric(df["a"])

# save to csv
df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

sample considering

```
c = '11 1663.315780 6.045E-26 6.292E-01.06980.304 2724.04150.64-.009550'

d = c.replace(" ", ",")
print(d)
```

will give

```
11,1663.315780,6.045E-26,6.292E-01.06980.304,2724.04150.64-.009550
```

or

```
print(c.split(" "))
```

will give

```
['11', '1663.315780', '6.045E-26', '6.292E-01.06980.304', '2724.04150.64-.009550']
```